# CSS Box-model seems to be broken in Chrome 15 (latest stable release)

Tags: margin, css

I thought the days of checking box-model issues between *modern* browsers were long gone...

I have been having problems getting Chrom[e|ium] to display my website correctly, and I've managed to create this really simple example of what's going wrong:

The HTML:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="left">LEFT!</div>
    <div class="right">
        RIGHT! 16px margins on everything.... What's that??? → → → 
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
div.left {
    float: left;
    margin: 16px;
    padding: 16px;
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    background: #fee;
}

div.right {
    margin: 16px;
    padding: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
        background: #eef;
}
```

A screenshot of the problem:

[image]

A live demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/g105b/BJuYR/

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but removing the left margin on `div.right` sorts it out: http://jsfiddle.net/BJuYR/13/

Comment: I can't understand why that changes it ...

Comment: The same is true in Chrome 2 on Windows and Safari 5.1 on Mac, so I reckon this is a long-standing WebKit issue. I’m not sure either — I think it’s something to do with the calculation of how much space is left for `#right` to take up after `#left` is floated. WebKit seems to 1. be subtracting `#right`’s left margin from that space and 2. not be positioning `#right` any further to the left that it would do if the margin wasn’t there. Firefox does 2., but doesn’t do 1.

Comment: The issue also goes away if you remove `overflow: hidden;` from `#right` (see http://jsfiddle.net/BJuYR/14/), although of course then `#right`’s outline extends behind `#left`.

Comment: It’s less a box model issue, more a float/overflow/margin layout issue, and those areas are hairy.

Answer (score 1):

No other browser behaves like WebKit does here.

[Searching WebKit Bugzilla](https://bugs.webkit.org/query.cgi?format=specific&product=WebKit) for "block formatting context margin" yields this very similar result:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19123

As a workaround, you can use the fix I proposed in a comment:

> removing the left margin on `div.right` sorts it out:
>   http://jsfiddle.net/BJuYR/13/